# How risky is putting sensitive files up on webroot?

Tags: web-hosting, security

I understand that having anything sensitive under webroot is not smart; someone may be able to access it via url. However, I do not have a choice with my web host (iPage) as they limit my server space to just the web root.

So my question is: how risky is it to just have sensitive files in a directory in a webroot with just simple forbidden public access? Any insight on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: The 'sensitive files' are an installer for our startup's software and the php files that allow the download / control sql access.

Comment: Oh, and any recommendations on a new web host would also be very much appreciated. 

Currently looking at bluehost and liking what I see!

Comment: How sensitive are we talking on a range from nuclear missile codes to your grandmothers favorite recipe?

Comment: Hi Stephen, thank you for your query! I made an edit explaining what my sensitive files are.

Comment: What is "simple forbidden public access"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your risk is greater than if the files were completely outside the webroot simply because they are accessible on the web. This means you are relying on the web server to secure something which would otherwise be freely available to anyone with the correct URL. This results in an increased attack surface with exposure to web server vulnerability exploits, whereas leaving them outside the webroot requires an attacker to obtain a greater degree of system access.

On the other hand, some thoughts about the effectiveness of [Security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) with regards to file or directory names:

If the *name* of a specific file or directory is very difficult (or nearly impossible) to guess, e.g., its name is a [GUID/UUID](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uuidgen), then IMO the risk is greatly decreased because the difficulty of brute-forcing such a name is comparable to brute-forcing a complex password. Of course, this also means that legitimate access to such files becomes more difficult, but that's what bookmarks are for. Unauthenticated access might even be considered secure (to an extent; highly vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks) if the names are "sufficiently hard to guess" (this is the general criterion applied to a password).

Relying heavily on security through obscurity is generally discouraged, but my view is that we are indirectly practicing it all the time by using passwords.

Comment: Thanks for your answer darton!

My question was more aimed at asking how risky it is to put files OUTSIDE webroot vs. on webroot with security settings as you mentioned.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. Was actually editing my answer because I had some additional thoughts on that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've decided that moving the host is the ideal answer to this problem. 

Do you have any recommendations on web hosts?

Comment: @ink, I've been with http://dreamhost.com for about 5 years and have zero complaints or desire to move. And this is coming from someone who was CTO of a web hosting company.

Comment: *Security through obscurity is generally discouraged?* Not in my world! It is a very common practice but obviously not relied upon entirely. Observe best security practices always.

Comment: @closetnoc, you make a good point. Answer adjusted.

Comment: @dartonw I hope you did not take my comment as negative. Just different experiences! I was a web host prior and an IT/IT Business/Internet Services consultant all the way back to and including coding router stuff for the original ARPA-Net. Yes. I am that old!! In my circles, we tried to confuse things to make hacking extremely hard. But I realize that did not happen in most places. I like your answer BTW.